# How do I know if I'll receive the Chase Freedom Unlimited sign-up bonus offer?

Tags: credit-card, bonus, credit-card-offers

I recently signed up for a Chase Freedom Unlimited® credit card with the hopes of qualifying for the bonus. My application for the card was successful, but I didn't see any mention or confirmation of the bonus offer during the application process, and I don't see any mention of it on my Chase account (e.g., on the benefits page). Can I just assume I'll qualify for the bonus offer if I hit the spending requirements in the alloted time frame, or is there an extra step I need to take to get the bonus?

From [Chase](https://creditcards.chase.com/cash-back-credit-cards/freedom/unlimited):

> Best Freedom bonus offer: $200 cash back
>
> after you spend $500 on purchases in your first 3 months from account
>   opening.* Same page link to Offer Details Offer only available when
>   applying directly with Chase.
>
> This product is available to you if you do not have this card and have
>   not received a new cardmember bonus for this card in the past 24
>   months.

With the details being:

> $200 Bonus This product is not available to either (i) current cardmembers of this credit card, or (ii) previous cardmembers of this
>   credit card who received a new cardmember bonus for this credit card
>   within the last 24 months. You will receive 20,000 bonus points with
>   this bonus offer, which can be redeemed for $200 cash back. To qualify
>   and receive your bonus, you must make Purchases totaling $500 or more
>   during the first 3 months from account opening. ("Purchases" do not
>   include balance transfers, cash advances, travelers checks, foreign
>   currency, money orders, wire transfers or similar cash-like
>   transactions, lottery tickets, casino gaming chips, race track wagers
>   or similar betting transactions, any checks that access your account,
>   interest, unauthorized or fraudulent charges, and fees of any kind,
>   including an annual fee, if applicable.) After qualifying, please
>   allow 6 to 8 weeks for bonus points to post to your account. To be
>   eligible for this bonus offer, account must be open and not in default
>   at the time of fulfillment.

Note: I haven't received a new cardmember bonus for this card in the past 24 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chase sent me a separate email telling me that the card comes with the aforementioned bonus offer.

Answer (score 8):

I've done a half a dozen or so of these over the years and not one of them did anything more than send me the credit card once I was approved.  While I can't guarantee you that you'll get the bonus, there's no reason to expect that you won't.  You applied for their bonus promotion and you were approved.  That should mean that it's a done deal.

Comment: Same experience. The offer is never mentioned again, which can make you feel quite anxious anout getting cheated, but I always got it after fulfilling the requirements.

Comment: @Aganju: Same here, but I wouldn't call not getting the bonus "getting cheated", since it's not as though you paid anything for the card. (Bar a few minutes of your time filling out the application.)

Comment: In my case, there were annual fees attached; and credit score is typically a bit impacted. I would not have taken the offer without the attached bonus. - It _is_ cheating for me if you get an offer and take it, and the offerer walks back on it - called 'bait and switch'.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same experience as others here. The company likely won't mention the bonus again, but your purchases are still being recorded. As long as you meet the spend requirements, you'll wake up to the bonus in your account one day.

One thing to note is that it often takes several weeks after you complete the spend requirements for the bonus to show up in your account, so don't worry if you don't see it right away.

If it's been a few months, I'd suggest calling customer service to verify you met the spend requirements and everything, just to give yourself some peace of mind.

Answer (score 0):

(I know this is 5 months late...)

> You will receive 20,000 bonus points with this bonus offer, which can be redeemed for $200 cash back. To qualify and receive your bonus, you must make Purchases totaling $500 or more during the first 3 months from account opening.

Do you have a user account at https://www.chase.com?  Almost certainly what will happen is that after three months the 20,000 points will be added to your Ultimate Rewards balance.

Answer (score 0):

You can secure message them on the website or call the number on your card to confirm the details of the bonus and that it has been applied to your card.  I'd recommend secure message so you will have it in writing for future reference.

Note that some other issuers (e.g. Citi) already have this information presented in the online banking interface.